# Python: how to apply function uppercase in multiple columns pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply, uppercase

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

I have this code to make a function uppercase  for values string:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','elo'],
    'Alpha':['Arizona AZ asdf hello abc','Georgia GG asdfg hello def','Newyork NY asdfg hello ghi','Indiana IN asdfg hello jkl','Florida FL ASDFG hello mno'],
    'Naise':['hello abc','hello def','hello ghi','hello jkl','hello mno'],
    'Helo':['sample al','sample bel', 'sample cel', 'sample del', 'sample el'],
    'Food':['chicken','pizza','rice','ice cream','bakwan'],
    'Age':[11,12,13,17,29]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1


def upper_consistent(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper() if x.dtype == "object" else x) 
    return df
```

and I'm trying to apply the function to uppercase the two columns only

```
df1[['Name', 'Naise']] = df1[['Name', 'Naise']].apply(upper_consistent)
```

but i get error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

how do i get the result according to the desired output?

Comment: modifying only the columns is more efficient: ``df1.columns = [col.upper() for col in df1 if col in ['Name', 'Naise']]``

Answer (score 3):

Why not just apply `.str.upper()` to each column with a lambda function?

```
df1[['Name', 'Naise']] = df1[['Name', 'Naise']].astype(str).apply(lambda col: col.str.upper())
```

Comment: ohhh great idea broo, so no need to create a separate function?

Comment: Right @Niken, that's the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your function receive a dataframe as parameter, don't use `apply` but call your function with your dataframe as parameter:

```
def upper_consistent(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper() if x.dtype == "object" else x) 
    return df

df1[['Name', 'Naise']] = upper_consistent(df1[['Name', 'Naise']])
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    Name                       Alpha      Naise        Helo       Food  Age
0    TOM   Arizona AZ asdf hello abc  HELLO ABC   sample al    chicken   11
1   NICK  Georgia GG asdfg hello def  HELLO DEF  sample bel      pizza   12
2  KRISH  Newyork NY asdfg hello ghi  HELLO GHI  sample cel       rice   13
3   JACK  Indiana IN asdfg hello jkl  HELLO JKL  sample del  ice cream   17
4    ELO  Florida FL ASDFG hello mno  HELLO MNO   sample el     bakwan   29
```